# VueJs 3 Закрытие окна корзины

Tags: vue.js, typescript, vue3

Есть проект на vue 3. Там есть небольшая корзина суть в том, что когда в неё добавляется товар она открывается посредством переменной:

```
let fixedCartIsOpen = ref(true);
```

Мне не обходимо закрывать это окно при переходе на другую странциу, но данная переменная притягивается в компонент таким способом:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Cart',
  setup () {
    const { fixedCartIsOpen } = Catalog();
    ...
  }
  ...
})
```

И получается, что просто привсвоить переменной ref(false)
я не могу, поскольку она является константой, хотя при клике она меняется и закрывает корзину. Так как заставить её закрыться через код? Просто я не особо дружу с vue3, не говоря уже о ts на котором он написан.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем-то всё как обычно решается с помощью 1 строки и в моём случае выглядит так:

```
fixedCartIsOpen.value = !fixedCartIsOpen
```

Comment: Лучше не менять const на let. Изменение данных внутри объекта будет работать.

Comment: @SwaD Ок, только странно, что в документации этот момент про такое присвоение не прописан.